# Password protected website

Tags: php

So I want to make a password protected website , that works only one time so the website cannot be abused , only admin which is me would have access to generate password without it the people cannot access index of that site , could anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the password after someone used it to view the page, oder add a column `used` with `tinyint`, when `used=0` the password could be used to view the page. When `used=1` it has already used, so it is not valid.

The comparison need to be done in the SQL where it validates it.

The changing of `used` or remove of the password needs to be done directly after it has been validated.

Add code so that the answer would be better and we know what you done exactly till this time.

Comment: Hmm excuse me but im begginer could you  give me a sample code?

Comment: when you tried it yourself, post your code, then we could help you!

Comment: Dude... Shall I use at least a membership script?

Comment: I want something like this.When somebody visits my website they should log-in to check index otherwise it doesn't work , but when they register i need to manually activate them understand now?

Comment: Please post your code sample or something you done till now, this is a support forum not a request forum.

Comment: @M.Becker - and now you've discovered why people don't answer low-quality questions ;-)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Already discovered this, but hope never fades^^